# Заменить последнюю единицу в двоичной записи числа на ноль

Tags: математика, битовые-операции, системы-счисления

Собственно, задача в условии.

```
7->6 (так как 111 - 110)  
6->4 (110 - 100)  
5->4 (101 - 100)
```

Проблема в том, что нельзя использовать строки, циклы и ветвления(с этим задача становится элементарной).
Только арифметику и битовую арифметику.

Просьба подсказать в каком направлении копать.
Самостоятельно удалось решить только для частных случаев, либо с использованием запрещенных элементов (типа поиска последнего вхождения подстроки или цикла смещения)

Comment: без цикла не знаю, с циклом так можно, например:

    var a=6,i=0;
    while (a>>i<<i==a) i++;
    a^=1<<--i;
    console.log(a);//4

Comment: С циклом и я знаю. =) В состоянии найти единичку в строке.
Но задача именно без.
В частном случае, когда число начинается только с единиц, а заканчивается только нулями, оно решается

($a << 1) & $a.

Но в общем случае явно надо использовать что-то, что дает равное число 1 и 0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[@knes](/users/2825/knes) пример из учебника

```
 a = a & (a - 1);
```

Comment: А что за учебник?

Comment: @knes Рейнгольд, Нивергельт, Део. Комбинаторные алгоритмы. Теория и практика. стр 13. Алгоритм 1.2 (подсчёт единиц в наборе)

Comment: @knes: гуглится по довольно неочевидному словосочетанию ["bit twiddling hacks"](https://www.google.com/search?q=bit+twiddling+hacks).

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать битовую арифметику, все элементарно: x = x & ~1;

Comment: Нет. Это заменяет **последний** бит, а нужно — последний ненулевой. В вопросе: `110 -> 100`.

Answer (score -1):

Задача на самом то деле простая:

Надо просто логически поразмыслить:

1. Если число в двоичной записи заканчивается на 0, значит число четное (и обратно)
2. Если число в двоичной записи заканчивается на 1, значит оно нечетное (и обратно)
3. Чтобы заменить последнюю цифру с 1 на 0 надо просто отнять 1

То есть в Java псевдокоде:

```
int replaceLastOne(int number) {
    if(number%2==1)
       return number-1;
    else
       return number;
}
```

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, похоже задача другая. @VladD указал на это в своем комментарии к аналогичному ответу @Uta.

Comment: Во-первых, вы использовали ветвление (if), во-вторых, надо именно последнюю ЕДИНИЦУ, а не цифру. Тем не менее, в более простых случаях такое решение прокатит.